# Is there a way to write text to a file and then read off it into an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a Discord bot with Discord.js and am implementing a punishment system.. I need to store information in a text file so when I restart the bot, the information isn't lost. I need to store info like Username, User ID, Date of Punishment, DUration, Type of Punishment, End Date.

Comment: Yes, use the [filesystem](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html). Did this not show up in searches?

Comment: I think you're looking for something like [conf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/conf)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) to read/write the information from/into a `json` file.